# TinyMCE ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) skins (vue)

Tags: vuejs2, console, tinymce, skins

I'm facing the console error issue with tinymce on vue.js. It works correctly both localhost and server hovewer editor throws me error on server (doesn't throw error on localhost).
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URA7m.png)

Here is my import section
[I've tried import files both dynamically and statically, hovewer errors continue to exist]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">

import Editor from "@tinymce/tinymce-vue";
import "tinymce/tinymce";

// Theme
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme";


// Skins
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css";
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css";
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css";

// Plugins
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen";
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste";
import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autoresize";

import "../../../../../../node_modules/tinymce/icons/default";
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved my issue with writing `:init="{content_css: false, skin: false}"` property to editor tag